# How to left join on a dataframe based on dates on `dbplyr`

Tags: r, dplyr, dbplyr

I am trying to join two `data.frame`s based on a condition. Consider the following situation where I have `df_a` and `df_b`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# Dummy data A
df_a <- tibble(
   id = c("a", "b", "c", "a"),
   text = c("hi","why", "bye","cry"),
   created_date = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-02-02"), as.Date("2020-03-01"), as.Date("2020-04-04"))
)

# Dummy data B
df_b <- tibble(
  id = c("a", "b", "c", "a"),
  group = c("GROUP A","GROUP B","GROUP C", "GROUP C"),
  start_date = c(as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-01-01"), as.Date("2020-02-04"))
)

> df_a
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id    text  created_date
  <chr> <chr> <date>      
1 a     hi    2020-01-01  
2 b     why   2020-02-02  
3 c     bye   2020-03-01  
4 a     cry   2020-04-04

> df_b
# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id    group  start_date
  <chr> <chr>  <date>    
1 a     GROUP A 2020-01-01
2 b     GROUP B 2020-01-01
3 c     GROUP C 2020-01-01
4 a     GROUP C 2020-02-04

# Current solution
d_current_sol <- df_a %>% 
  left_join(
    df_b %>% 
      distinct(id, .keep_all = T), by = "id"
    )

> d_current_sol
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  id    text  created_date group  start_date
  <chr> <chr> <date>       <chr>  <date>    
1 a     hi    2020-01-01   GROUP A 2020-01-01
2 b     why   2020-02-02   GROUP B 2020-01-01
3 c     bye   2020-03-01   GROUP C 2020-01-01
4 a     cry   2020-04-04   GROUP A 2020-01-01

# Desired solution
> d_desired
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  id    text  created_date start_date group  
  <chr> <chr> <date>       <date>     <chr>  
1 a     hi    2020-01-01   2020-01-01 GROUP A
2 b     why   2020-02-02   2020-01-01 GROUP B
3 c     bye   2020-03-01   2020-01-01 GROUP C
4 a     cry   2020-04-04   2020-02-04 GROUP C
```

As you can see in `df_b` the start date for `id = a` is first `2020-01-01` and then `2020-02-04`.

What I would like is for any row in `df_a` after `2020-02-04`, it's associated group to be `"GROUP C"`.  This is illustrated in the final data frame `d_desired`

However, with a traditional `left_join` where we match the row to a single row item, we only get the earliest entry (`d_current_sol`). This would be easy enough to do using `map()` and using a custom function with `mutate()`, however, SQL doesn't support that when translating `dplyr` queries.

Does anyone know a way of doing this through the `tidyverse` paradigm? As I will be using `dbplyr` to run this on a PostgreSQL database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this?

```
df_a %>% 
  left_join(df_b, by = "id"  ) %>% 
  filter( created_date >= start_date) %>% 
  group_by(id, created_date) %>% 
  top_n(1,start_date)
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   id, created_date [4]
  id    text  created_date group   start_date
  <chr> <chr> <date>       <chr>   <date>    
1 a     hi    2020-01-01   GROUP A 2020-01-01
2 b     why   2020-02-02   GROUP B 2020-01-01
3 c     bye   2020-03-01   GROUP C 2020-01-01
4 a     cry   2020-04-04   GROUP C 2020-02-04
```

Comment: Ah perfect, yes! Thanks :)

Comment: Ah actually this doesn't work on all DB backends as `top_n` isn't supported

Comment: whats about `filter(start_date == max(start_date))`

Comment: This takes the closest `start_date` however, we would want every `start_date` until a new `start_date` to be in `GROUP A` then `GROUP C`

Comment: Have you filtered after grouping? Thus, `group_by(id, created_date) %>% filter(start_date == max(start_date))`

Comment: Yep! Sorry just realised there was an error in my data and the dates weren't correct and so wasn't seeing the stuff turn up correctly! Apologies :)